# Private var is accessible from outside the class

Tags: swift, swift2

This was done in Playground, just to simplify.

```
class MyPrivateVar
{
    private var priv: String?
}

var myInstance = MyPrivateVar()

myInstance.priv = "Something"
```

No compiler warning. In fact auto-complete is showing `priv` without a problem. 
My understanding is that outside the boundaries of {} of the class, I'm not supposed to be able to see a private anything, `func` nor `var`.

Am I missing something?

Comment: adding tag swift2 as this is no longer true in swift3

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Access modifiers in Swift are implemented differently than other languages. There are three levels:

`private`: accessible only within *that particular file*

`internal`: accessible only within the module (project)

`public`: accessible from anywhere

Unless marked otherwise, everything you write is `internal` by default.

The [Swift blog had a post about access control](https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=5) when the features were introduced in beta 4, and [Apple's documentation has a chapter](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AccessControl.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH41-XID_29) as well.

Comment: "_Private access restricts the use of an entity to its own defining source file. Use private access to hide the implementation details of a specific piece of functionality._". I guess when they say 'file' they actually mean it. It does not make too much sense to have a `private` scope restricted not to own class, but to the physical file it's in. I guess having classes in the same file is _not_ just convenience, it has functional meaning. Maybe has something to do with 'private' headers not copying outside.

Comment: The blog post linked in the answer goes into some of their reasons for this non-standard system, and they have [another post on why they didn't include "protected"](https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=11) that goes into more detail.

Comment: In Swift 3, this will change so `private` limits the declaration to the current scope and `fileprivate` (the new access modifier) will do what `private` was doing before Swift 3. [This article](https://swifting.io/blog/2016/08/17/22-swift-3-access-control-beta-6/?utm_campaign=This%2BWeek%2Bin%2BSwift&utm_medium=web&utm_source=This_Week_in_Swift_100) has a good summary of the access modifiers in Swift 3.

Answer (score 8):

***Note: this answer is for Swift 2***

---

*The Swift Programming Language* states:

> Swift provides three different access levels for entities within your
>   code. These access levels are relative to the source file in which an
>   entity is defined, and also relative to the module that source file
>   belongs to.

If you wan't to test `private` access level with Swift, the following step by step may help you.

1/ Create a new Xcode project.

2/ Create a file, **MyPrivateVar.swift**, and add the following code in it:

```
class MyPrivateVar {

    private var priv: String? = nil

}
```

3/ Create a second file, **MySecondClass.swift**, and add the following code in it:

```
class MySecondClass {

    init() {
        var myPrivateVar = MyPrivateVar()
        myPrivateVar.priv = "some string"
    }

}
```

Xcode will immediatly give you a Swift compiler error message:

> 'MyPrivateVar' does not have a member named 'priv'

4/ Now, remove the two previous files from your project and create a single file **TwoClassesInAFile.swift** with the following code in it:

```
class MyPrivateVar {

    private var priv : String? = nil

}

class MySecondClass {

    init() {
        var myPrivateVar = MyPrivateVar()
        myPrivateVar.priv = "some string"
    }

}
```

This time, you will get no Swift compiler error message and you will be able to access `MyPrivateVar`'s `priv` private property from `MySecondClass` because `priv` and `MySecondClass` are in the same file (your **TwoClassesInAFile.swift** file).

Furthermore, access levels also work for global variables. For example, Xcode won't give any compiler error if the following code is part of the same **ViewController.swift** file:

```
import UIKit

private var globalPrivate : String? = nil

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        globalPrivate = "some string"
        println(globalPrivate)
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

}
```

However, if you define `globalPrivate` outside of **ViewController.swift**, Xcode will generate an error message:

> Use of unresolved identifier 'globalPrivate'

Comment: Was using Playground simply to double check. Original problem took place on a view controller file in a project. I noted that I was using Playground to simplify issue.

Comment: **Point number 4 is wrong in swift 3 and xcode 8.**
class AccessModifiersClass {
    
    private var privV : String?
    internal var inteV : String?
    public var publV : String?
    var defV : String?
    
}


class CheckPoint {
    
    init() {
        globalPrivate = "some string"
        let lVar = AccessModifiersClass()
        lVar.priv = "Public"
        lVar.inteV = "Internal"
        lVar.publV = "Public"
        lVar.defV = "default"
        
    }
    
    
}