# Sinch video doen't want to work on iOS (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, sinch

So basically I want to enable Sinch Video in iOS application.

For testing purposes I've created SinchManaevger which is singleton and I instatiate it in AppDelegate:

```
class SinchManager: NSObject, SINClientDelegate, SINCallClientDelegate {

    static let sharedInstance = SinchManager()

    var client: SINClient?

    func initSinchClientWithUserId(id: String) {
        if client == nil {
            if case .Authenticated(let currentUser, _) = SessionManager.sharedInstance.state.value {

                self.client = Sinch.clientWithApplicationKey("xyz", applicationSecret: "xyz", environmentHost: "sandbox.sinch.com", userId: currentUser.username)
                print("sinchClient")
                print(client!)
                self.client!.delegate = self
                self.client!.setSupportCalling(true)
                self.client!.enableManagedPushNotifications()
                self.client!.start()
                self.client!.startListeningOnActiveConnection()

            }
        }
    }

    func clientDidStart(client: SINClient!) {
        print("clientDidStart")
        self.client!.callClient().delegate = self
    }

    func clientDidStop(client: SINClient!) {
        print("clientDidStop")
    }

    func clientDidFail(client: SINClient!, error: NSError!) {
        print("clientDidFail")
    }

    func client(client: SINCallClient!, didReceiveIncomingCall call: SINCall!) {
        print("didReceiveIncomingCall")
        let sinchVC = SinchVC(username: currentUser.username)
        let sinchNC = DNMMainNC(rootViewController: sinchVC)

        sinchVC.call = call
    }
}
```

And I've created Sinch ViewController which is initialized with username which will be called:

```
class SinchVC: UIViewController, SINCallDelegate {

    private let videoController = SinchManager.sharedInstance.client!.videoController()
    private let audioController = SinchManager.sharedInstance.client!.audioController()
    private let callClient: SINCallClient
    private var call: SINCall!

    let username: String

    private var mainView: SinchView { return view as! SinchView }

    override func loadView() {
        view = SinchView()
    }

    init(username: String) {
        self.username = username
        self.callClient = SinchManager.sharedInstance.client!.callClient()

        super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


        call.delegate = self

        self.mainView.videoView.addSubview(self.videoController.localView())
        self.videoController.localView().contentMode = .ScaleToFill

        if self.call.direction == SINCallDirection.Incoming {
            self.audioController.startPlayingSoundFile(self.pathForSound("incoming.wav") as String, loop: true)
        }

        if self.call.details.videoOffered {
            print("video offered")
            self.mainView.videoView.addSubview(self.videoController.localView())
            self.videoController.localView().contentMode = .ScaleToFill
        }

        mainView.videoView.addSubview(self.videoController.localView())
        mainView.answerButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(answer), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
        mainView.declineButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(decline), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        self.audioController.enableSpeaker()
    }

    func pathForSound(string: String) -> NSString {
        let nsSt = NSBundle.mainBundle().resourcePath! as NSString

        return nsSt.stringByAppendingPathComponent(string)
    }

    func answer() {
        call.answer()
    }

    func decline() {
        call.hangup()
    }

    func callDidEstablish(call: SINCall!) {
        print("callDidEstablish")
    }

    func callDidEnd(call: SINCall!) {
        print("callDidEnd")
    }

    func callDidProgress(call: SINCall!) {
        print("callDidProgress")
        self.audioController.startPlayingSoundFile(self.pathForSound("ringback.wav") as String, loop: true)
    }

    func callDidAddVideoTrack(call: SINCall!) {
        print("callDidAddVideoTrack")
        mainView.videoView.addSubview(self.videoController.remoteView())
    }


}
```

Problem is when I try to call from my app to other phone with my app nothing happens (didReceiveIncomingCall delegate method doesn't get called at all)

If I try to call from my app to SinchVideo sample app then video call gets initiated normal. But when i call from SinchVideo app to my app nothing happens in my app. So probably i've forgot to add some notification or something to tell my app when the call is incoming. If you could help I would be very grateful. Thanks

EDIT: I managed to make didReceiveIncomingCall work but now call.answer isnt working. (nothing happens when call.answer is called and i see that my phone is ringing)

Comment: tou must specifically reference call property from delegate method or it wont work - solved

Comment: Can you edit the code for completeness with the working solution? If its to much work i can do it adn post as an answer you accept.

Comment: @cjensen I've edited post.

Comment: Did my answer below help? If so can you mark it as answered please.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what  DNMMainNC does in your did recieve incoming call,

```
let sinchNC = DNMMainNC(rootViewController: sinchVC) What does DNMMainNC do?
sinchVC.call = call  // private var?
```

But its looks kind of weird to set a private var call from your code, should that not be public or have a constructor like your init but with a call

Comment: Reading this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26087447/private-var-is-accesible-from-outside-the-class makes me a bit upset, why would you restrict private to the physical location rather then classes.